# How to check if the json file has a specific element?

Tags: python-3.x, bash

How to check if ["foo"]["bar"] is present in a json file from BASH script? tried below:

```
$ cat myJson.json | if ( python3 -c "import sys,json; json.load(sys.stdin)['foo']['bar']"); then echo "found foo-bar"; fi
$ found foo-bar
```

it works, but it prints below if the element is not present:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'baz'
```

but bash script don't fail anyway.

**Update:**

Tried try-except:

```
cat myJson.json | \
if (
python3 -c "
import sys,json
try:
   json.load(sys.stdin)['foo']['bar']
except KeyError:
   #exit with non-0.
   sys.exit(1)
") then echo "found foo_bar"; FOUND_FOO_BAR=true;
fi
echo $FOUND_FOO_BAR
$ found foo_bar
$ 
$
```

I am expecting "true" to be printed after `found foo_bar', but it doesn't, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: wrap a try/catch around it.

Comment: Try with export FOUND_FOO_BAR=true

Comment: @Bsqare, tried taht already, didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [jq](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-jq/) tool:

```
jq 'map(has("foo.bar"))' myJson.json && echo "found foo-bar"
```

Comment: thanks, but I cannot install jq and python is already installed, so I can use it.